# Change marker colors based on values - Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I want to change the marker colors based on values , so i tried the below piece of code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("E:/values.csv")
def SetColor(x):
    if(x < 100):
        return "orange"
    elif(100<= x <=200):
        return "white"
    elif(x > 200):
        return "black"


import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objs as go
trace1 = go.Scatter(
                    x=df['Date'], y=df['Show1'], 
                    line = dict(color=list(map(SetColor, df['Show1']))),
                    mode='markers',name='Show1' 
                   )

fig = go.Figure(data=[trace1], layout=layout)
pyo.plot(fig,filename='final_plot.html')
```

But i am getting below error msge

```
ValueError: 
    Invalid value of type 'builtins.list' received for the 'color' property of scatter.line
        Received value: ['black', 'black', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'orange']
```

What am i missing here

Comment: Any help on this?

Comment: It looks like, according to [the docs](https://plot.ly/python/reference/#scatter), `line` does not accept a list of values. You're using `mode='markers'`, so you could try setting the colors for the markers instead, because that does accept a list.

Comment: Can you pls explain a bit more...with example code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your current code isn't working is because you're setting `line` colors which doesn't accept lists, instead of `marker` colors, which *does* accept lists.

Instead of

`line = dict(color=list(map(SetColor, df['Show1'])))`

you can use

`marker = dict(color=list(map(SetColor, df['Show1'])))`

to set the `marker` colors.